# Tailwind CSS - Why some of the classes don't work time to time

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've been learning CSS and then got into Tailwind CSS recently. It's fun, but time to time some of the classes don't work properly and it's making me mad.

For instance,

```
<h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold">./prototurk</h1>
```

I can't make this text bigger, for instance 4xl, or even text-[36px] does not work time to time. I'm saying time to time cause I've seen it worked before, but I'm thinking maybe its related to the other elements somehow? Since it's workable in the play.tailwind.

This goes for bg-red-500, but if I do bg-blue-500 that works. or for

```
<button class="text-sm text-white rounded ml-auto bg-red-300 w-12">YENİ</button>
```

text-xs or bg-red-400... does not work :D it's crazy...

I'm also facing an issue with this part:

```
 <div class="bg-red-100 flex items-center justify-center m-3 border h-9 rounded-full">
                                </div>
```

it's not rounded AT ALL. rounded-xl or something else works but I can't get the circle. Any help would be very appreciated. (kinda n00b though, please consider that)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./stil.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header
        class="dark:bg-black dark:text-white flex justify-between items-center px-4 border-b border-gray-200 h-14 fixed w-full z-20 bg-white">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold">./prototurk</h1>
            <p class="ml-2 pt-2 text-gray-400 font-semibold text-sm">v3.0.0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block w-[600px]">
            <input placeholder="Ara"
                class="placeholder:p-4 placeholder:text-sm font-medium mr-2 w-full border-solid border border-gray-300   rounded h-10">

        </div>

        <button
            class="dark:bg-white dark:text-black w-28 h-10 bg-slate-700  px-4 text-white rounded text-sm  transition-all hover:mr-4">Giriş
            Yap</button>




    </header>
    <div class="flex h-[calc(100vh-56px)] ">
        <aside class="border border-b-2 overflow-auto  h-[calc(100vh-3.5rem)] fixed top-[3.5rem] ">

            <div class=" bg-[#ffffff] w-[250px] space-y-1 m-1 p-1 pl-0 pr-2 pt-1 text-[15px] border-r-2 border-b-2
            border-gray-100 ">
                <a href=" #" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9   ">
                    Anasayfa</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">Keşfet</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 - hover:rounded h-9">Makaleler</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">Soru &
                    Cevap</a>
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9 ">Ders
                        İstekleri</a>
                    <button class="text-sm text-white rounded ml-auto bg-red-300 w-12">YENİ</button>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div
                class="bg-[#ffffff] w-[250px] m-1 p-1 pl-0 pr-2 pt-4 text-[15px] border-r-2 border-b-1 border-gray-100  ">
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">HTML</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">CSS</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">JavaScript</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">PHP</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">MySQL</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">Laravel</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">Phyton</a>
                <a href="#" class="p-4 flex items-center hover:bg-gray-100 hover:rounded h-9">Git</a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="h-52 bg-slate-500 flex flex-col justify-items-end items-center">
                    <div class="flex w-[250px] justify-between bg-black z-10 fixed bottom-0">
                        <div class="flex items-center m-3 bg-gray-50 border-2 rounded-md justify-evenly  ">
                            <img class="w-5 h-5 m-2  -mr-1" src="./images/light.png" alt="light-mode">
                            <button class="w-24 p-2 text-sm">System</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center m-3 border-2 bg-gray-50 rounded-md justify-evenly">
                            <img class="w-5 h-5 m-2 -mr-3" src="./images/en.png" alt="light-mode">
                            <button class="w-24 p-2 text-sm">EN</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>



        </aside>

        <main class="flex-1 ml-[280px] mt-[4rem]">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold m-3">Kendine değer kat!</h2>
                    <p class="m-3">İyi bir kariyer için, doğru bir başlangıç gerekir. Prototürk'de bir çok dil ve
                        teknolojiye ait
                        derslerle
                        doğru bir başlangıç yapmaya hazırsın!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex gap-4 p-3">
                <div class="border h-[200px] w-52 flex justify-center items-center rounded-md">
                    <div class="block h-full">
                        <div class="grid place-items-center h-full ">
                            <div class="">
                                <div class="bg-red-100 flex items-center justify-center m-3 border h-9 rounded-full">
                                </div>
                                <img class="h-24 w-24 flex items-center justify-center m-6 " src="./images/sb-icon.png"
                                    alt="sb-icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-auto w-auto flex justify-center items-center">
                                <button class="rounded border w-20 h-8 m-2">HTML</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block ">
                                <div class="border bg-gray-300"></div>
                                <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 justify-center m-2">
                                    <p>15 Ders</p>
                                    <p>5 Video</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>












    </main>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "media",
  content: ["./**.{html,js}", "'./components/**/*.{html,js}',"],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'serif': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'mono': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'display': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],


    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Did you try that as !text-xs or !bg-red-400?

Comment: Thank you, that's the important tag from the js, right? 
Unfortunately did not work though :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably, some classes don't import. Can you try this code? I changed the content file paths.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: "media",
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}", './src/components/**/*.jsx',
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'serif': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'mono': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],
      'display': ['montserrat', 'Georgia'],


    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

edit: You can also try your code on Tailwind Play. https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Comment: First thing first, thank you! I've changed it (also got rid of a small typo, "]" in the end of content) but unfortunately it has not worked. (If i need to do anything extra besides saving&refresing please let me know)

I've tried the code on play.tailwind and it works. That's why I'm madder about it honestly :D